# From SimpleXMLElement to SimpleXMLIterator

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a nice function that converts a (simple, duh) xml to an array, and to do so it uses the `SimpleXmlIterator` class.

It works quite well, but I'd like to make it accept not only xml source strings or `SimpleXmlIterator` objects, but `SimpleXmlElement`s too since I use them way more often that iterators (that I use just in that function, actually).

What I did so far was

```
$iter = new SimpleXmlIterator($xml->asXML());
```

but to me it's like passing through Tokyo to get from Paris to London. After all, `SimpleXmlIterator` extends `SimpleXmlElement`, so is there a better way to convert a `SimpleXmlElement` object to a `SimpleXmlIterator`?

Comment: Plus one for "passing through Tokyo to get from Paris to London!" :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleXMLIterator at the beginning by setting the second parameter in http://php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-file.php

```
$yourSimpleXMLIteratorObject = simplexml_load_file("your_file.xml","SimpleXMLIterator");
```

all Objects resulting, are now SimpleXMLIterator-Objects

Comment: It may be good as a general strategy, but it's not what I asked. What if one simply doesn't have control over the XML object creation? (Also, please link pages in English when they're available.)

Answer (score -1):

Why not parse all your XML into `SimpleXMLIterator` objects to begin with if you plan to use them as such?

As far as I know there is not an easy way to convert/cast from `SimpleXMLElement` to `SimpleXMLIterator`. These classes simply wrap a libxml resource so you *would* think there would be a way to obtain a resource handle and pass it into `SimpleXML*` constructors, but if there is it's news to me.

Comment: I figured that out from the beginning. But then again, why is there a `SimpleXMLElement` class, to begin with? The answer is the same.